# CUDA coalesced access of FP64 data

Tags: cuda, double, gpgpu, gpu-warp

I am a bit confused with how memory access issued by a warp is affected by FP64 data.

- A warp always consists of 32 threads regardless if these threads are doing FP32 or FP64 calculations. Right?
- I have read that each time a thread in a warp tries to read/write the global memory, the warp accesses 128 bytes (32 single-precision floats). Right?
- So if all the threads in a warp are reading different single precision floats (a total of 128 bytes) from the memory but in a coalesced manner, the warp will issue a single memory transaction. Right?

Here is my question now:

- What if all threads in the warp try to access different double-precision floats (a total of 256 bytes) in a coalesced manner? Will the warp issue two memory transactions (128+128)?

PS: I am mostly interested in Compute Capability 2.0+ architectures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A warp always consists of 32 threads regardless if these threads are
>   doing FP32 or FP64 calculations. Right?

Correct

> I have read that each time a thread in a warp tries to read/write the
>   global memory, the warp accesses 128 bytes (32 single-precision
>   floats). Right?

Not exactly. There are also 32 byte transaction sizes.

> So if all the threads in a warp are reading different single precision
>   floats (a total of 128 bytes) from the memory but in a coalesced
>   manner, the warp will issue a single memory transaction. Right?

Correct

> What if all threads in the warp try to access different
>   double-precision floats (a total of 256 bytes) in a coalesced manner?
>   Will the warp issue two memory transactions (128+128)?

Yes. The compiler will emit a 64 bit load instruction which will be serviced by two 128 byte transactions per warp when coalesced memory access is possible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer my friend. I am willing to accept it, but I would also be grateful if you could comment on the 32-byte transactions. Under what circumstances do they happen? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @AstrOne: If every thread in the warp needs to load 8 or 16 bit types, these can be serviced with 32 byte transactions. You can also force the compiler to emit 32 byte transactions if you wish.